# Which data structure to use in python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following, admittedly short, "table" in form of csv:

```
"Some Class"|"Type 10"|"Type 11"
"Class 1"   |  0.971  |  0.968
"Class 2"   |  0.995  |  0.996
"Class 3"   |  0.970  |  0.971
"Class 4"   |  0.969  |  0.970
"Class 5"   |  0.992  |  0.998
"Class 6"   |  0.992  |  0.998
"Class 7"   |  0.980  |  0.984
"Class 8"   |  0.973  |  0.981
"Class 9"   |  0.969  |  0.978
"Class 10"  |  0.992  |  0.998
```

While building a python class with methods that will retrieve coefficients from the above "table", and methods that will use them in computations, I wonder which data structure to use.  **The class will explicitly require input as for which *Class #* to use.** *Type 10* and *Type 11*, are always involved in the computations.

**Update:** above, *Class #* are strings, a short description of the class type actually.

So far, I am experimenting with things like the following:

```
ec['class'] = ec.get('class', {'type_a': float(), 'type_b': float()})
```

which then can be used, for example, as

```
ec['class']['type_b']
```

What are things to take care about and what are best practices in such a case?

Comment: I suggest [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) it supports fast csv loading, fast lookup, vectorised operations

Comment: I would like to be as independent as possible in the implementation of the class.

Comment: You can use pandas to load the data, then transfer it into whatever class you want.

Comment: @TheBlackCat the OP doesn't want to use an external module for whatever reason, the question is more a class design question

Comment: Whats does `ec` mean in your context?

Comment: @EdChum indeed. I want to either use existing data structures in python, or design my own data structure for such data. So, it's more about how to store it, rather than how to get it in.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl ec stands for emissivity_coefficient(s)

Comment: Couldn't you just build a dictionary like so?: http://pastebin.com/tnyhmCJz

Comment: Are those class numbers typical? If so, why not just use a list of tuples (or namedtuples)? If the class numbers are _not_ necessarily a contiguous list of integers starting from 1 (or another low number), you could use a dict of tuples, with the class number as the key.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl WoW! Thanks for the `is_number()` checker. I will learn a lot through this :-)

Comment: @PM2Ring No, they are actually strings. A short description of a class I would say.

Comment: Ok. Then a dict of tuples should work well - dicts in Python are fairly efficient in memory and dict lookup is fast.

Comment: In the case of tuples, I have to get rid the "Type A", "Type B" names (of columns in the csv), right? For this short table, it might be easy. But, if the coefficients are too many, for the sake of readability, isn't it better to keep the `'key': vaue` logic?

Comment: Oh. I thought there were only two columns of coefficients. You should explain in the question that that table is a highly simplified version of your real data. But anyway, you can keep the field names if you use [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). They're quite efficient & don't take up much RAM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73324/discussion-between-nikos-alexandris-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the classes are always in order, I guess the simplest thing to do is to have a list within a list. For me it's more convenient when I need to use the numbers in calculations.

I assume that you read the data in lines and get a list. Just be aware that class 1 is now at position 0 in the table. Each class list has a sublist with Type 10 in pos 0 and Type 11 in pos 1.

```
data = ['Some Class|Type 10|Type 11',
'Class 1|0.971|0.968',
'Class 2|0.995|0.996',
'Class 3|0.970|0.971',
'Class 4|0.969|0.970',
'Class 5|0.992|0.998',
'Class 6|0.992|0.998',
'Class 7|0.980|0.984',
'Class 8|0.973|0.981',
'Class 9|0.969|0.978',
'Class 10|0.992|0.998']

# To get rid of the title
data.pop(0)

ec = []

for datarow in data:
    dsplit = datarow.split('|')
    ec.append([dsplit[1],dsplit[2]])
```

You might also be able to shorten this piece of code with a list comprehension, but it eludes me for the moment.